# Oracle 11g: How to manipulate a String value?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jdeveloper

I am sorry for a beginners question, but google is not helping me.

i have a following value in .xsl

```
<imp1:Street>
<xsl:value-of select="db:Street"/>  
</imp1:Street>
```

This value is taken from DB and written into Text File.
The value can have many Chars but i need to get only the first 4.
For example ADDA NASA 11  --> ADDA.

I can't understand where can i manipulate this value in Oracle 11g.
Until now i just tried the sub-string function:

```
   <imp1:Street>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring((db:Street),0,8)"/>  
   </imp1:Street>
```

But i am not sure if this is a correct approach.
What is the best way to manipulate Strings?

Comment: Do you want to do that inside the database (using SQL) or do you want to do that in Java?

Comment: What is, in your opinion, the simplest solution for this?

Comment: i used this java code for testing: String d = "SFO AP01183285012";
System.out.println(d.substring(0, 8)); But i don't get it where to implement it.

Comment: So you want a Java solution?

Comment: There is no "best way" to do anything.  What do you mean, "I don't get where to implement it?"  You are not giving enough context here, and very hard to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: As i formulated it in my question, the value of "Street" is taken from oracle DB and writen in a flat file. Between the DB and the flat file i need to change the value from "SFO AP01183285012"-->"SFO AP01". How can I do it?

Comment: If the Street attribute is always referred with substring after writing it to the file, then better do the SUBSTR(street,1,4) in the db itself while writing to the file